# Convert SOAP response to xstream object

Tags: java, xstream

I have Soap response from another application which i am trying to convert to an object using **"XStream"** using below code;

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
file file = new File("file.xml");
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
String reqXMLString = "" //Stream converted to XML
System.out.println(xstream.fromXML(reqXMLString)); **//Error line**
```

file.xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:validationErrors>
            <messages>
                <message>
                    <code>1020</code>
                    <text>Filed 1 is mandatory</text>
                </message>                  
            </messages>
        </soap:validationErrors>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When i try to convert this xml to an java object. i am getting below error;

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: soap:Envelope : soap:Envelope
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
```

So may I know, **how to convert a soap response into java object using XStream** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any aliases/converters configured in your example, so it probably doesn't know how to deserialize your soap:Envelope

Comment: So, I need to configure like this : http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html

Comment: The link to xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html is not active.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the SOAP body as OMElement from response for mapping against object. You may try like this:(Assuming your class to which you are mapping your response(xml file) is `ValidationErrors`

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.xml");
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(fr);
    StAXSOAPModelBuilder smb = new StAXSOAPModelBuilder(xmlStreamReader);
    SOAPEnvelope senv = smb.getSOAPEnvelope();
    OMElement omelement = senv.getBody().getFirstElement();
    try{
        Iterator<OMElement> childIterator = omelement.getChildElements();
        while(childIterator.hasNext()){
        OMElement childEle = childIterator.next();
        String childName = childEle.getLocalName();
        if("validationErrors".equalsIgnoreCase(childName)){
            XStream stream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
            stream.setClassLoader(ValidationErrors.class.getClassLoader());
            stream.alias("validationErrors", ValidationErrors.class);
            ValidationErrors response = (ValidationErrors)stream.fromXML(childEle.toString());
           }
        }
        catch(XStreamException e){
           e.printStack();
      }
```